# Corners of button not staying rounded when using constraints constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, uibutton

I have two buttons in a stack view. I have used an extension of UIButton to round the outside corners. This works on the 7Plus which I designed for in storyboard but as soon as I run on a smaller device size in the simulator it stops working and I can only round corners on the left side of either button and not the right. Any ideas?

On a 7Plus
[image]

On a 7
[image]

These are the extensions I'm using

```
extension CGSize{
    init(_ width:CGFloat,_ height:CGFloat) {
        self.init(width:width,height:height)
    }
}
extension UIButton{
    func roundOneSide(topCorner: UIRectCorner, bottomCorner: UIRectCorner){
        let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                 byRoundingCorners: [topCorner , bottomCorner],
                                 cornerRadii:CGSize(6.0, 6.0))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer1
    }
}
```

I have also tried the following code to no avail. It can only successfully round corners on the left when constraints come into play.

```
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 6, height: 6)).cgPath
    facebookBtn.layer.mask = maskLayer
    facebookBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: you can use segment control for this type of button design. It is bit easy to use and customise it. Please look at it.

Comment: In this question you want to give outside corners for both buttons so you can use its default cornerRadius property to give it.

Comment: @JeckyModi He can not give default corner radius otherwise the buttons got cornered where they touch each other.

Comment: He made an extension of topCorner and bottomCorner so its possile that it can give corner to button as he wants ? @dahiya_boy

Comment: @dahiya_boy I really suggest him to use segment Control for this situation

Comment: @JeckyModi I think he need to do `maskToBounds = true` thats it. It allows to give effect on layers. Segment is also a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was an easy fix. I just needed to round the corners in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    loginBtn.roundOneSide(topCorner: .topLeft, bottomCorner: .bottomLeft)
    facebookBtn.roundOneSide(topCorner: .topRight, bottomCorner: .bottomRight)
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to use viewDidLayoutSubviews() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use you use segment Control as jerky said or
Try this below code:

// For login button

```
   UIBezierPath *cornersPathLeft = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:buttonLogin.bounds  byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft|
UIRectCornerTopLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];

    //Create a new layer to use as a mask

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayerLeft = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    // Set the path of the layer 

    maskLayerLeft.path = cornersPathLeft.CGPath;
    buttonLogin.layer.mask = maskLayerLeft;
```

// For FB button

```
    UIBezierPath *cornersPathRight = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:buttonFB.bounds  byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight|
UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayerRight = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayerRight.path = cornersPathRight.CGPath;
    buttonFB.layer.mask = maskLayerRight;
```

**NOTE:**

do `maskToBounds = true` it allows to give effect on the layers.

-

### **Difference Between MaskToBounds and ClipsToBounds**

**MaskToBounds**

Any sublayers of the layer that extend outside its boundaries will be clipped to those boundaries. Think of the layer, in that case, as a window onto its sublayers; anything outside the edges of the window will not be visible. When `masksToBounds = NO`, no clipping occurs.

When the value of this property is `true`, Core Animation creates an implicit clipping mask that matches the bounds of the layer and includes any corner radius effects. If a value for the mask property is also specified, the two masks are multiplied to get the final mask value.

**ClipsToBounds**

The use case for clipsToBounds is more for subviews which are partially outside the main view.

For example, I have a (circular) subview on the edge of its parent (rectangular) UIView. If you set clipsToBounds to YES, only half the circle/subview will be shown. If set to NO, the whole circle will show up. Just encountered this so wanted to share

**Conclusion**

**MaskToBounds** are applied for the sublayer of any view. Like here OP added layer over button but it does not give effects. I mean layer is not bounds properly.

**ClipToBounds** are applied on the subVies of any view. Assume you have you have a view( says, viewBG ) and and now you added another view (says, upperView), now you dont wanted to see view upper to look outside the viewBG. ViewUpper always bounded inside its superview. so in this case you have to true the clipstobounds.

**Practical experience**

Try this below code in swift

```
let viewBG : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        viewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        self.view.addSubview(viewBG)

        let viewUpper : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -50, y: -50, width: 100, height: 100))
        viewUpper.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        viewBG.addSubview(viewUpper)
```

**Output** 
1. When i done `viewBG.clipsToBounds = false`

[image]

2. When i done `viewBG.clipsToBounds = true`

[image]

Comment: I dont difference between masktobounds and cliptobounds. Can you please explain it in simple way ?

Comment: @JeckyModi Check my answer explanation. If you still have issue then let me know.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation

Comment: @JeckyModi You can better understand after I added practical exmple above.

Comment: This cliptobound I understood well becuase I used it but when to use masktobound Can u put example of it ?

Comment: What would the code for Swift 3 look like on the first code you posted. I just tried something similar but it will only round the left corners and not the right when constraints are used. The code is added at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable clipToBound property of button in storyboard;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different, very simple method of curving the corners on a UIButton or Label.

1. Click on button
2. Click on identity inspector
3. Then add an attribute in the identity section
4. Key path is `layer.cornerRadius`
5. Set as Number
6. Finally give a value, the higher the value, the more rounded the corners are.

[image: layer.cornerRadius]

Comment: I am aware of this method however I am only trying to round 2 corners.

Comment: Oh my apologies